# Handling crashes / exceptions from Google Play Console with no stacktrace in my app's source code

Tags: java, android, exception, google-play-console

I have 2 exceptions (crash clusters) in my apps google play console (Release management -> Crashes) that I cannot identify because the root of the exceptions is not in my app source code and there is no additional information message.

I cannot simulate any of these errors in development (phone or simulator).

The first one is related to serializable objects, but I use Serializable or Parceable (I did not find anything usefull on google):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable (Parcel.java:1468)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1416)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:686)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1330)
  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1079)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:711)
  at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel (Fragment.java:141)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray (Parcel.java:1254)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel (FragmentManager.java:380)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable (Parcel.java:1437)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1343)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:686)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner (BaseBundle.java:1330)
  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel (Bundle.java:1079)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle (Parcel.java:711)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped (ActivityManagerNative.java:3153)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:3417)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: 
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal (ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues (ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy (ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal (ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable (Parcel.java:1463)
```

The second one is related to fragment transactions I believe, but I cannot find anything that can help me (or at least simulate in development)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment (FragmentManager.java:1696)
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:770)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2392)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2187)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2148)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2049)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:719)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7000)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:441)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: The error might happen in your activity's onCreate() method, when you call intent.getParcelableExtra() and the object cannot be decoded. Add more logs to your app !

Comment: I have about 25 activities and 12 external libraries. How do I narrow it down? Also, why would it work for most users (and in development) and not in some isolated cases?

Comment: That's the hard part, reproducing the problem. I suggest you set your app up on Fabric's Crashlytics, you will see more infos on the conditions of the crash (phone model, RAM left ...). You can also log your own infos in Crashlytics if you manage to catch the exception